# Why is parsing a tpl file in CodeIgniter giving me an error on a web server?

Tags: codeigniter, parsing, smarty

So, my friend that owns the domain that we are working on set up a live development server for me to upload my files to.  I had previously been developing on WAMP.  I uploaded the CodeIgniter files to the web server(along with the application) and updated the config files.  When everything in the config was working, I refreshed the page and got an error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /blah/blah/html/application/frontend/views/overall_header.tpl on line 1
```

This is the very first TPL file called in the script.  I use the CI template parser library to parse TPL files.  It worked absolutely fine on WAMP, but now is giving me this error.  The TPL file is just pure HTML.

Any ideas?

PS:  The web host is Media Temple.

Base Command

```
<div id="header">

    <div id="toolbar">

        <ul>
            {TOOLBAR}
        </ul>

        <div id="search">

            <form action="#" method="POST">

                <input type="text" name="criteria" value="Enter search criteria, then press enter." class="text-input">

            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="banner">

        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html" title="Home Page"></a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="navigation">

        <ul>
            {MAIN_NAVIGATION}
        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: post the code of `application/frontend/views/overall_header.tpl on line 1`

Comment: CI try to include your tpl file like a PHP file. It's strange it works on WAMP for you. Add `.php` to the filename.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is a problem with difference between new line characters on Windows and Linux systems. On local you use WAMP (Windows), so you use \r\n as new line characters. On hosting (I hope, Linux-like hosting?) it not working correctly, because Linux standard new line char is \n . To solve this you need to change all \r\n to \n before putting files on hosting.
For preventing this in future use editor/IDE which can work with linux-like line chars and may be change WAMP environment settings belongs to new line characters.
This is invisible symbols and you use it in any files what contain line breaks. Check this settings in your editor:
[image]

Comment: thanks for the response, but I do not use \r\n in any of the files.  It's just pure HTML with the occasional {SOME_TAG} thrown in.

Comment: I changed my previous answer a bit by adding an image. May be it will more clarify for you.